# Run a batch file in a completely hidden way

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm looking for some way to run a batch file (.bat) without anything visible to the user (no window, no taskbar name, .etc..).

I don't want to use some program to do that, I'm looking for something cleaner. I've found [a solution](http://www.computing.net/answers/dos/run-batch-file-invisiblestealth/14270.html) that uses VBScript, but I don't really like using VBS, either.

Comment: Haha! Definitely not. I'm developing a Windows service which will run a batch file every now and then.

Comment: Windows services don't run as batch files.  They run as services.  You need to clarify the question--as written and with comments it makes no sense to me.

Comment: I has a Windows service that runs batch files. Not that the service is a batch file.

Comment: What language are you writing your service in?

Comment: there is hstart too.

Comment: If you're already developing a service, why not use NSSM to create a service out of your compiled file?

Comment: Just to add to the list of programs - [Hidden Start](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html).

Comment: I think your link is down.

Comment: "a solution" has link rotted, [archive here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121028054849/http://www.computing.net/answers/dos/run-batch-file-invisiblestealth/14270.html)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Save this one line of text as file `invisible.vbs`:

```vb
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

To run any program or batch file invisibly, use it like this:

```
wscript.exe "C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs" "C:\Some Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat"
```

To also be able to pass-on/relay a list of arguments use only two double quotes

```vb
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "" & WScript.Arguments(0) & "", 0, False
```

Example: `Invisible.vbs "Kill.vbs ME.exe"`

**Solution 2:**

Use a command line tool to silently launch a process : [Quiet](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/quiet/index.htm), [hidecon](http://code.kliu.org/misc/hidecon/) or [hideexec](http://code.kliu.org/misc/hideexec/).

Comment: Why 4 double quotes, could you please explain?

Comment: What if we needed to start a program hidden?

Comment: @Starx VB syntax. `&` means concatenate strings. Strings are enclosed in double quotes (`"`). Consecutive double quotes (`""`) inside string delimiters means a literal double quote (`"`). So, four double quotes (`""""`) would be a string literal of one character, a double quote (`"`). Put it together, and `"""" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """"` would become `"<argument>"`, where `<argument>` is the first command line argument passed to the script.

Comment: Cool and simple solution. Checked it, it works. Thanx.

Comment: Finally, after hours of wasted time searching and trying, this one liner VBS does the trick.  Simplest solution for starting batch file silently from scheduled task, thank-you.

Comment: `CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False` is it possible to get this code in `JAVA ` or atleat in Windows bat file since I am not supposed to use VB..please help ..

Comment: How to modify it so it passes all arguments? It would be more convenient to pass the arguments without quoting them.

Comment: Doesn't this still require you to create a batch file for putting the `wscript.exe "C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs" ...` inside of?

Comment: `hideexec` seems to have some difficulties to run elevated commands.

Comment: The call without parameters works, the unspaced call with parameters works, but I can't find a way of getting the latter to use a script that itself contains spaces and therefore needs to be quoted. Is there a way to call the script passing in `"C:\Some Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat" Param1 Param2`? // EDIT: One workaround is to use an unspaced link to the spaced script.

Comment: How to use this solution: **1:** create the batch file you want to run (ie at `C:\apps\mybatch.bat`). **2:** create the invisible.vbs script (ie at `C:\apps\invisible.vbs`). **3:** create a new shortcut by right clicking on the *background* (empty space) of the folder where you want to save the shortcut, mouse over `New` in the context menu, click `Shortcut`.  For the "Location of the item" enter `wscript.exe "C:\apps\invisible.vbs" "C:\apps\mybatch.bat"`.  Double clicking this shortcut will launch the batch file silently.

Comment: This is the one that actually works. I tried Quiet and nircmd, but they actually flicker a cmd terminal when they run, so they don't accomplish the one thing they are supposed to.

Comment: `invisible.vbs` file is deleted by antivirus software. may be we need some other way here.

Answer (score 33):

To Hide batch files or command files or any files.... Use Windows XP built in `IExpress.exe` utility to build a .EXE out of the batch file. When using `IExpress` make sure you check the run hidden option and check mark all the boxes about not showing anything. After you create your .exe place it in whatever run command folder you choose and you will never see it come up.

Comment: Oh, good solution actually.

Comment: is there anything equivalent to lexpress.exe in newer windows versions like windows 7?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ It is in windows 7....just tested it

Comment: This does not seem to work on Windows 10 64 since the "Command.com" no longer seems to be present

Comment: I can confirm the comment by @ArneS. You can build the EXE but it won't run due to files missing (i.e. Command.com).

Answer (score 14):

I don't like the VBScript solution.

Download and copy [nircmd.exe](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to your `%systemroot%\system32` folder, then add this command to first line of your batch:

```
nircmd.exe win hide ititle "cmd.exe"
```

You can also change the title of your batch file terminal window by `title` command to avoid from hiding all `cmd` windows, like this:

```
title MyBatch
nircmd.exe win hide ititle "MyBatch"
```

Comment: I use this exact method, but failed for some time that nircmd don't hide the cmd window, just minimized into taskbar, and cannot restored by click on it. Don't know why...

Comment: `nircmd.exe execmd` might also be of interest, it solved my use case. It starts a command already hidden.

Comment: This sounds like it would flash a `CMD` window before it manages to hide it. Also, it sounds like it will hide all cmd instead of just your own—even the title hack is just a hack which doesn’t account for all scenarios such as other scripts with MyBatch in their title.

Answer (score 12):

Run the script via an at job without making it interactive:

```
at 11:00 script.bat
```

---

Another solution, if you don't mind installing something like Python, you could simply create a script and run it with `pythonw` (the linked version for GUI operations). Since you aren't using any graphical APIs, the window will not show. Simply use calls to `os.system()` and it will mimic a batch script, as it is the same as typing the strings into the command line.

Example:

```
import os

os.system("tasklist > C:\tasks.txt")
os.system("ipconfig /all > C:\netinfo.log")
```

Comment: But how would I run this command?

Comment: You would have to either schedule a scheduled task or write a service.

Comment: examples added.

Answer (score 11):

use [Cmdow](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/) is a Win32 commandline utility for NT4/2000/XP/2003 that allows windows to be listed, moved, resized, renamed, hidden/unhidden, disabled/enabled, minimized, maximized, restored, activated/inactivated, closed, killed and more.

Run a batch file hidden passing it parameters:-

> cmdow /run /hid mybat arg1 "arg 2"

Comment: cmdow is detected as a malware by most antivirus products. Hence it would be difficult to use this solution in places other than you own PC.

Comment: Is it open source? There's no point in using a third party app that's not open source and could be packing trojans when you could do the same thing with by running harrymc's 1 line vbscript (see he answer at the top of the thread).

Comment: Well, it is open source, so that's pretty awesome. Can get the source code here: https://github.com/ritchielawrence/cmdow

Comment: @thebunnyrules Is there anywhere that has a compiled version of it? The source is useless to me without a C++ compiler. And I really don't want to download and install a C++ compiler for a single app lol.

Answer (score 11):

If your Batch File can fit into one line and so many characters, then just use a Shortcut by right clicking inside a  folder put in a random directory, and skip through the rest of the wizard, and lastly right click on the shortcut just created and click properties and under target, input what you would usually put in a bat file. And Bobs your uncle!

Pros:

```
 No Command Window
 Ability to use an icon
 Same Functionality of bat file
```

Cons:

```
 Limited to one line, so many characters
```

Comment: The only problem is that you can't associate a filetype with a shortcut. So if you want to open a with a batch script by double-clicking on it in explorer you still need a .bat-file.

Comment: I'm still trying to find Uncle Bob, is here around anywhere!!

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist For this use case i would create a starter pyw script and then assign the file type to the script. The script contents would be e.g. `import subprocess, sys; subprocess.Popen(['path/to/prog.exe', sys.argv[1]], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True, creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS)` and the assignation to the script would be `"path\to\pythonw.exe" "path\to\starter_script.py" "%1"`. I found [RapidEE](https://www.rapidee.com/en/about) to be a pleasant tool to assign filetypes. See also John T's answer for Python v2 ways to run programs.

Comment: btw, one of my personal script tool functions has the signature `doubleclick(*args)`, which does the above. When args is just `[filepath]` it opens `filepath` with its default program.

Comment: I made a mistake in my first comment, i meant [FileTypesMan](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html), not RapidEE (which is also very handy, it edits environment variables).

Answer (score 8):

You can also create an [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script:

```
#NoTrayIcon ; To prevent momentary icon pop-up
run whatever.bat arg1 arg2,,hide
```

Answer (score 7):

You can run it minimized easily.

```
start /MIN batch.cmd
```

Comment: or use /B instead!

Comment: `start` is `cmd` build-in command. It isn't available from Task Scheduler, etc

Comment: But to use `start`, you open yet another `cmd` console window (while briefly). Anyway, @gavenkoa, to use `start` from anywhere, just run it via `cmd`: `cmd /c start /MIN batch.cmd`.

Answer (score 6):

The excellent [Bat To Exe Converter](https://www.computerbild.de/download/Bat-To-Exe-Converter-2345613.html) will convert your `.bat` or `.cmd` file to an `.exe` file.

[image]

It has a simple UI. You can choose not to have a console window by selecting an `Exe Format` of  `XX Bit | Windows (Invisible)` option. Also, it allows you to assign an icon, set a password and several other options.

Answer (score 5):

Using Windows7, you can use the "Scheduled Task" control panel to schedule a batch file to run in the background invisibly with specified permissions and even as the "SYSTEM" account.  See screenshot below:

[image]

Furthermore, although with not as many capabilities, you can also create a invisible batch script task like this from the command line using the "AT.exe" command without the '/interactive' option.

Comment: Hidden checkbox just hides the task from the Task Scheduler user interface (

Comment: Running a task as “SYSTEM” when it doesn’t need “SYSTEM” privileges (and hasn’t been scrutinized for security weaknesses, and hardened) as a bad idea; see [the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6568736/1672723#6568823).

Comment: My understanding is that what makes the task run hidden is the option "Run whether user is logged on or not."  Like Sourav Ghosh wrote, the checkbox "Hidden" just keeps Task Scheduler from displaying the task definition.  For more information see: https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-run-a-scheduled-task-without-a-command-window-appearing/

Answer (score 5):

YET ANOTHER way, from C/C++, is to use the CreateProcess function with the CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag.  It has a lot of extra power not shown here.  This is just the minimum you need to replace system() or the _spawn() family.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

// Spawn creates a cmd.exe window.  CreateProcess doesn't.
//if ( _spawnl( _P_WAIT, szFileNameBAT, szFileNameBAT, NULL ) ) {  
if ( !CreateProcess( szFileNameBAT, szFileNameBAT, NULL, NULL, false,
                     CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi  ) ) {
  MyErrorFunc( "CreateProcess( \"%s\" ): %d", szFileNameBAT, GetLastError() );
  goto MyErrorHandling;
}

WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

Comment: Correct answer for WINAPI approach. Here is [source code and application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507347/hide-command-window-of-bat-file-that-executes-another-exe-file/56111754#56111754) as addition to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Despite I've already answered this here's another approach. The different here's that the batch script can self-hide itself during it's run.You'll need two additional scripts though - [windowMode.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat) and [getCMDPid.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat) (both are containing `.net` code). Here how then can be used:

```
@echo off
call getCmdPid
call windowMode -pid %errorlevel% -mode hidden

echo this should be written into log despite the cmd window is hidden>log
echo ending the log>>log
exit
```

Answer (score 3):

I did it successfully with [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) this way:

1. download nircmd.exe from the [link](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
2. create your .bat file
3. the first line of .bat file has to be this: `nircmd.exe win hide ititle "cmd.exe"`
4. select both files and create a self extract file using winrar
5. in "general" tab, check "create autoextract file" box
6. in "advance" tab select "autoextract" button
7. there is a new window and select "mode" tab then select option: "hide everything"
8. select tab "update" and select option "overwrite existing files"
9. Select "general" tab and define a destination folder for extraction if you wish and in the box "Excecute after extraction" write the full path where your .bat will be extracted.
   Ex: if you define extraction folder as: "c:\windows\" then the full path to excute after extraction will be: "c:\windows\file.bat" (in the case your .bat is named: file.bat)
10. click accept on all windows

Now you will have a .exe file that after you doble click on it and install it, your .bat will run totally hidden.

Answer (score 3):

> **Adding my answer here from another [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1012610/how-do-i-create-a-windows-process-that-runs-in-the-background) since it was a duplicate and I don't see this solution here so now there are 17 different answers
> for how you can run a batch file hidden. I will delete my answer on that post at some point in the near future.**

Create your batch script with your batch logic and commands in it, and then create a new file with `.VBS` extension, use the below logic (example I provided below) and just plug in the full path to your `.CMD` or `.BAT` file with the `PING -t <IPAddress>`, etc. commands so it executes the batch in a hidden manner not showing the command window when it is executed.

Where the logic in the example below specifies `C:\Folder\BatchFileName.cmd` change that to point to the batch script with your commands you are running manually, etc. now.

Save the `.VBS` file and schedule it with `Task Scheduler` [Problems scheduling a task on windows7](https://superuser.com/questions/1005192/problems-scheduling-a-task-on-windows7/1005216#1005216) to run on an indefinite schedule for your needs.

Otherwise, just double-click on the `.VBS` file to run the infinite `PING` command you put in the batch file you point it to as-needed.

**NOTE:** *I believe this is where I got this script logic from but it works reliably for the same purpose you need here which is to ensure the command window is hidden when a batch file is run [Server Fault Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window)*

**EXAMPLE VBS SCRIPT RUN COMMAND LINE BATCH HIDING CMD WINDOW**

```
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Folder\BatchFileName.cmd" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

**Note: This looks for a bat file with the same name. You can change bat to cmd in script, if needed with this example.**

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count <= 0 Then
    WScript.Quit
End If  

bat = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\")) & WScript.Arguments(0) & ".bat"
arg = ""

If WScript.Arguments.Count > 1 Then
    arg = WScript.Arguments(1)
End If

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """" & bat & """ """ & arg & """", 0, False
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm created [RunApp](https://github.com/futurist/runapp) to do such a job and also using it in my production env, hope it's helps.

The config like below:

**file: config.arg**

```
:style:hidden

MyBatchFile.bat
arg1
arg2
```

And launch `runapp.exe` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do any special.

If you are running the batch files from a windows service, they should be hidden by default unless you enable the "Allow service to interact with desktop" option on the service.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to hide the window for a batch file called from an explorer context menu, and also needed to add quotes on the parameter. None of the answers worked for me, so I'm adding my own solution.

I had this on the registry "command" for an explorer context menu:

```
cmd /c C:\mypath\myprogram.bat "%1"
```

So to replace it I had to create a vbs like this:

```
WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell").run "cmd /c C:\mypath\myprogram.bat """ & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Save in a place like `C:\mypath\myscript.vbs` and call it like this on the registry:

```
wscript "C:\mypath\myscript.vbs" "%1"
```

Note that the .bat path can't have spaces, so replace it with the 8.3 filename. So for instance `C:\Program Files\myprogram.bat` have to be referenced as `C:\Progra~1\myprogram.bat`. To see the 8.3 filename use `dir /x`

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell and Batch files:
Wasif's answer was great, but it wasn't well received, and I think that people may not have understood it, so I am expounding on it as the comment I made to his answer wasn't legible on a single line.

Batch file:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\pg-start.ps1"
```

powershell file:

```
Start-Process cmd -Argument "/c START /B ./pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start -l pgdata/server.log -D pgdata/" -WindowStyle hidden
```

This works, Postgres runs in a hidden window.

This fixes the issue I was having where Postgres would die once the batch script completed, which I didn't want.

It may also be related to a terminal bug on Windows 11:
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/14366

Comment: The Batch file/PowerShell console window will display briefly anyway. While it maybe acceptable for you, I do not think it's what OP asked for.

Answer (score -1):

This works for windows 8 (possibly others)

1. Create a batch file as normal
2. Create a shortcut to the batch file
3. Right click on the shortcut > properties
4. Click Layout
5. Untick "Let system position window"
6. set left position tp -1000
7. click apply
8. Click on the shortcut and it will run but you wont see it :)

Comment: Really?  This won't show as a button on the taskbar?

Comment: This was the best solution for me since the batch file only allocated a folder to a drive letter during startup. Used to be you could create a shortcut and just tell it to not open a window. Another feature Microsoft removed.

Answer (score -1):

Using Powershell:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "Batch file path" -ArgumentList "args" -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Comment: But then you have the PowerShell console window.

Comment: I didn't end up with a powershell window showing at all this way, and the postgres server didn't stop, so it was a happy day for me!

Batch file:
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\pg-start.ps1"

powershell file:
Start-Process cmd -Argument "/c START /B ./pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start -l pgdata/server.log -D pgdata/" -WindowStyle hidden

Postgres runs in a hidden window.