# avoiding console window display when scheduled task runs batch file

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, batch, scheduled-tasks

I have a small batch file which xcopies some files from one folder to another which I've scheduled (via windows scheduled tasks) to run every 1 hour:

```
@echo off
xcopy c:\foo c:\bar /E /C /F /Y
```

Since this is my workstation, I'm most probably doing work when the task executes, and then the black dos console window is displayed (lasts 2-3 seconds) and steals window focus.

I don't wish to see the files copied and of course the batch file does not ask for any user input. Is there a way to avoid displaying the console completely?

Comment: Same question & Answers on ServerFault: [Run a .bat file in a scheduled task without a window](http://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window)

Comment: More preferable answer to the one Oliver gave http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568736/how-do-i-set-a-windows-scheduled-task-to-run-in-the-background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way)

Answer (score 2):

Check the "Run whether user is logged on or not" radio button.  Even if you select the same user you're logged in as, it will start and run silently, not stealing mouse or keyboard focus.
[Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-run-a-scheduled-task-without-a-command-window-appearing/)

Comment: It does run silently, but it also runs with a delay (I measured 18 seconds once) after the triggering event.

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass through `START` and `CMD` commands:

```
start "" /B "cmd /k "xcopy c:\foo c:\bar /E /C /F /Y""
```

Option `/B` tells the command interpreter not to create a new window.

Comment: But won’t it still display a Command Prompt window *for the* ``START`` *command itself?* [It has been reported](https://serverfault.com/q/9038/201794#9091) that this does not work.