# How to execute a command line after a specific program has been closed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

On Windows 7, I want to execute a command-line after I close a certain process (in my case ehshell.exe). The thing is, I'd prefer not to use any external program and I'd like to prevent having to use a .cmd with taskkill in it.

I already tried using the task planer to execute my command, but I failed to set an event trigger for the task because ehshell has no event ID for closing down. I even tried to enable logging for process creation and termination in gpedit.msc but that also didn't work as expected because it really logs **all** processes and not just a specific one.

Did I miss something? Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see how you can so this if the command prompt itself is not closing the process

Comment: Why don't you just start `eshell.exe` through a batch file that simply starts `eshell.exe` and runs whatever you want afterwards? The second command will not start until you close `eshell.exe` so it should work out fine.

Comment: Yeah right, `start /w` did the trick. Then I just had to hide the command window for which I used [hstart.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/hide-flashing-command-line-and-batch-file-windows-on-startup/) Thanks!

Comment: @dadadidudu vbscript is more modern than batch, I suppose is more powerful, and also wouldn't bring a cmd window up, and would be native, no third party program other than the little script you use to run the program!  ideal for a situation like this when there's no particular reason to use the command line  - vbscript mentioned briefly in a comment on an answer here http://superuser.com/questions/191149/how-to-execute-cmd-exe-silently   and also with an example here http://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file

Comment: @OliverSalzburg  &/questioner, can eshell be run outside of emacs? wouldn't he/you have to start emacs to run eshell?  I don't see eshell listed here http://linux.die.net/man/

Comment: @dadadidudu: If you found a solution to your problem, please post your own answer and mark it as the solution when the option becomes available. Thanks