# How to run bat file in background?

Tags: windows, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a completly hidden batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file)

I have a bat file that open a window and show a lot of information, which bother me a lot. How could I run the bat file in background?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file/531667

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a program called HStart (HiddenStart) which does it easily.

`hstart /noconsole c:\example.bat`

You can find hstart at ntwind.com 
[Hidden Start Utility](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html)

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to solve, depending on what you want, check the answers here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-vista-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-no-windows-dis

Per @Twisty's request, here's a copy of the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21130357/438544) answer:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Batch Files\ mycommands.bat" & Chr(34), 0 
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Put this in a file with `.vbs` extension, edit the location to your bat file and run `.vbs` instead.

Comment: As a highly valued Super User, I suggest you revisit this answer and [add more detail](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5177/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-answers-from-high-rep-users). Hyperlinks alone tend to point toward an answer without [actually being one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please edit your answer so that it includes the essential elements from your linked source.

Comment: @Twisty Sure, edited.

Comment: You can't always relay on `WScript` to handle such cases. I have disabled mine for security reasons.