# execute batch file in invisible mode

Tags: batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a completly hidden batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file)

How do I execute batch files at startup so that I won't see the cmd like black window.
I have this batch file which I use to attach vhd file on startup:

```
  @echo off
SET TEMPFILE="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%.TXT"
echo SELECT VDISK FILE=X:\sap.vhd >%TEMPFILE%
echo ATTACH VDISK>>%TEMPFILE%
DISKPART /s %TEMPFILE%
del %TEMPFILE%
```

Is there anything I could do to make the execution invisible?

Answer (score 3):

One way you could achieve this easily is through VBS.

Create a VBS with the following content:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Now you can run `wscript "[vbspath]" "[batchfile]"` to execute it silently.

Comment: what do I do with it?do I need to place it on the task scheduler, how am I supposed to call wscript.exe on startup together with the arguments that you supplied

Comment: There is an option for "Add arguments" in the "New action" window when adding an action.

Comment: I note that those newbies who want to get their feet wet using Visual Basic can try the 'express' version http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvbnet/a/LVBE_L1.htm

Comment: Windows has native interpretation of VBS, and has had for a long time...