# Batch file with DOS box hidden?

Tags: windows, batch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a completly hidden batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file)

On XP(SP3), is there a way to run a batch file without the DOS box being displayed at all (not just minimized)?

I tried several things, including "EXIT /B", "GOTO:EOF", and Erik Heijnen's [ConsoleTool](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/terminal-services/download.htm), to no avail.

Thank you.

---

Edit: Here's a simple solution when we just need to pass parameters: Add a Shortcut to the Deskop, and modify its Target parameter to pass parameters:

```
"C:\Program Files\Acme\MyApp\MyApp.exe" /MYSWITCH 123
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the helps. Turns out there's an easier solution if all we need is to pass parameters to an EXE.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked over on SuperUser, and has a lot of good answers:

- **[Super User: Run a completly hidden batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file)**

---

The top answer is:

Save this one line of text as file `invisible.vbs`:

> CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """"
>   & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0,
>   False

To run any program or batch file invisibly, use it like this:

> wscript.exe
>   "C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs" "C:\Some
>   Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat"

Answer (score 0):

convert batch process as service.

Create a new C# Windows application and call this method from main:

public static void RunBatchFile(string filename)
{
    Process process = new Process();

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;

// suppress output (command window still gets created)
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "> NULL";

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

}