# What is cmd's equivalent to Bash's & (ampersand) for running a command without waiting for it to terminate?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, process

In bash:

```
java -jar jarfile1.jar &
java -jar jarfile2.jar &
```

The ampersand lets you launch the first program, and then do another one while the first is still running.

How do I do this in cmd? (XP if it's relevant).

Comment: Please also see this answer: [Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/a/62646/1884287)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[start](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm) with the `/B` option

> Start application without creating a new window. The application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt the application

```
start /B java -jar jarfile1.jar

start /B java -jar jarfile2.jar
```

Answer (score 5):

I like the answer from [Nifle](https://superuser.com/questions/345602/what-is-cmds-equivalent-to-bashs-ampersand-for-running-a-command-in-a-sub-s/345605#345605) better but can't you just spawn a secondary cmd shell?  You can do this ad nauseam.

`cmd /c cmd /c cmd /c cmd /k echo Hello World!`

For a number of reasons, his answer is better, specifically if you want to wait until one process is done (like MSI installation, not so relevant to your case).  So, stick with `start`.

Comment: Yep, multiple cmd's is what I've been doing so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but for some applications it's ***very very*** relevant. If you use `start /B`, notice that when the shell terminates, the background processes also terminate. This however is not the case in `bash`

Comment: Are you sure ? When I run `start /B notepad` , closing the shell will not close notepad.