# Equivalent of (foo &>/dev/null &) in Windows shell

Tags: windows, command-line, shell

I'd like to run a particular application (let's call it `foo`) from the command line, but I don't want it holding up the terminal, putting any junk in the terminal from its output or error streams, and also want it to keep running even if I close said terminal. In Bash, I can do that using `(foo &>/dev/null &)`, but I don't know how I would do that in Windows shell. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way you would do this in Windows is:

```
start /B foo > NUL 2>&1
```

The `start` command will start a detached process, a similar effect to `&`. The `/B` option prevents `start` from opening a new terminal window if the program you are running is a console application (it is unnecessary for GUI applications). The `>` has the same meaning as in Linux, and `NUL` is Windows' equivalent of `/dev/null`. The `2>&1` at the *end* will redirect stderr to stdout, which will all go to `NUL`.

Comment: @KozRoss - This indeed prevents console app foo from holding up the terminal (console window). But I think foo does not continue if the terminal (console window) is closed. I believe closing the window terminates all console apps that are running within it. I know this is true if foo is a batch script, based on experiments. I haven't tested an exe or CScript.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent.

As described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/345602/what-is-cmds-equivalent-to-bashs-ampersand-for-running-a-command-without-w), calling a program in a way that doesn’t block the caller can be done with the `start` command, using the `/b` option. Dunno about output redirection in this case, though. You might have to wrap it in a batch file.

As for `> /dev/null`, it’s easy: `>NUL`. `NUL` is a DOS device name. The shorthand operator, however, is not available. You’ll have to go the manual way with `2>&1`. [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)’s some more info on that.