# Generic Stealth(er) for Programs

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a completly hidden batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file)

Is there any program (is it even possible) that I can call from a batch file (.bat) like this:

`> stealthlaunch PROGRAM`

And it will launch the program without showing any window (or anything) to the user?

***Info:*** I need to launch and updater for the company prog ( a series of interlinked xls files), and I've done a batch that automates te proces for me (copying files, patching files, installing new components), but I really hate do have people seeing the programs POP-UP

Comment: so, you want to launch a virus? :)

Comment: Not a virus... Added info

Comment: so you need the process running while the employees are currently logged in? do you need to run it in their account? can you run it while they are not logged in?

Comment: What's planned is for them to recebe it by mail. With instruction to execute it

Comment: Sending updates to internal software over email, with instructions for users to run an executable that remains completely hidden... Sure, that's *very* good security practice. **Not.**

Comment: Seriously though, you are already asking users to *manually run your program*. What is wrong with its progress being visible?

Comment: DOn't you guys have stupid bosses?? I know I sometimes have to do stuff I really really don't agree...

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you're looking for:

[Hidden Start](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html)

***From the site:***

> Console applications and batch files are regularly run at Windows
>   startup or in a schedule. The main inconvenience of this is that each
>   application opens a console window that flickers on the screen. Hidden
>   Start (or Hstart) is a lightweight command line utility that allows
>   you to run console applications and batch files without any window in
>   the background, handle UAC privilege elevation under Windows 7 and
>   Vista, start multiple commands in parallel or synchronously, and much
>   more.

***Screenshots***:
[image]
[image]

***Examples***:

```
Hstart is usually started by entering the following command line:

hstart /NOCONSOLE "batch_file_1.bat" "batch_file_2.bat" "batch_file_3.bat"
It is possible to redirect the console output of batch files into a log file:

hstart /NOCONSOLE /IDLE /D="E:\Backups" 
     "cmd.exe /c "MyDailyBackup.bat > backup-log.txt""
The /IDLE command line switch means that the backup process will run with the lowest priority class, and /D="" sets the starting directory of the batch file (required if the command line or script contain relative paths).
```

***Other resources(solutions):***

- [cmdow](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/) (sometimes detected as malware by AVs
- [HowTo run a batch file without it showing](http://forums.techguy.org/dos-other/644932-solved-howto-run-batch-file.html)
- [Windows Xp or Vista: How can I run a batch file in the background (no windows displayed)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-vista-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-no-windows-di)
- [Run a completly hidden batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file)