# Task Scheduler - how to run powershell script with multiple parameters?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am using powershell.exe as the Program and "`-Command "& C:\Windows\logon.ps1; exit $LASTEXITCODE"; ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`" as the Parameter, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Some things I would like:

1. getting a result in the task scheduler so I may know if everything worked allright or if there were errors
2. get the output of the script into a output.txt file (incremental file is possible?)
3. run the script hidden

Comment: You can use a batch file to do your work (using PowerShell), check the exit code/errorlevel, redirect output etc. You can of course [run it hidden](http://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file). If a batch file is not acceptable you can directly run the PS script hidden ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window), [2](http://www.faqforge.com/windows/how-to-execute-powershell-scripts-without-pop-up-window/)).

Comment: ok but if I want to give the arguments in the Task Scheduler itself, is it possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you forgot the - in your question but it's `-ExecutionPolicy`. If that script isn't signed then it won't execute that script also, you can use `bypass` as the executionpolicy to rule that out.

I doubt you can run scripts and commands one after another in the command line. Add the `exit $LASTEXITCODE` to the script and run it with the `-File C:\script.ps1`.

If by *run hidden* you mean no console window, I usually call my scripts like

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\script.ps1
```

and never see a window.

To get the output of your script into a file, pipe your commands into `Tee-Object`

```
"Hello World" | Tee-Object C:\output.file
```

You can name the file anything you like, implement logic in your script so the file name increments, or - my personal favorite - use YYYYMMddhhmmss in the file name.

---

**Update**

Also, taken from [Microsoft's Technet Page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx) on Powershell:

> Script blocks must be enclosed in braces ({}). You can **specify a script block only when running PowerShell.exe in Windows PowerShell**. The results of the script are returned to the parent shell as deserialized XML objects, not live objects.
>
> If the value of Command is a string, **Command must be the last parameter in the command , because any characters typed after the command are interpreted as the command arguments**.

Comment: ok most of the stuff worked, but I am still not getting the result in the text file. Could you give me more hints on that? The script is running automated in loggon but is not outputting it to a file. I'm running it with: `-file "C:\Eternita\Arruma_Maps.ps1" -executionpolicy bypass -noexit` Is it necessary that the output file exists so that it output or the script creates the file if it doesn't exists?

Comment: also which trigger should I use, I want it to run whenever I unlock the computer after screen saver or power on

Comment: You have to pipe the output to a cmdlet that will send the result to the file. Paste my example above and that should get you started. As far as which trigger to use that is a separate question and should be asked in a separate SE question.

Comment: i've used the tee-object in the script. what else? I don't understand