# How do I get a .bat file to run in Task Scheduler at PC Startup?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, tasks

Alright so I have been reading through the various answers on Super User for this question and no one has seemed to actually post a way of running a .bat file in **Task Scheduler** at PC startup. I would like to do this...

I tried having **Task Scheduler** start cmd.exe at PC startup with the arguments being the directory of the .bat file but it just does not work. Even if it says it does run the .bat the .bat's commands don't execute... How do I get it so it can run in **Task Scheduler** without this issue?

Comment: >"Even if it says it does run the .bat". So your .bat does run. What kind of commands do you have in the .bat? Commands executed in the taskmanager are **not** visible and can't interact with the users desktop so you won't **see** these commands executed (or any programs started with it). They run "invisible".

Comment: I am running deletion commands...

Comment: Can we see your .bat file content, task trigger and task arguments?

Comment: Have you selected "Run whether user is logged on or not" or "Run only when user is logged on" radio button? 
Do you actually need to do that via Task Scheduler? You can run your bat file at startup by pasting a shortcut to the .bat file into: 
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: Yeah I have...  Here is the .bat file I have so far: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WM9v4dS1 The files are not being deleted at startup as indicated in the lines f the .bat file...

Comment: How do you know your bat-file ran? Perhaps cmd.exe just executed with an error (which you don't see because it runs invisible). Please provide the screenshots of your task in the taskmanager. You stated you gave cmd.exe the arguments being the directory of the .bat. That won't work. You'll also need to include the batfile-name. So we need to see some screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply point the Scheduler's task to the .bat file itself. That is - in the *Actions* tab have *Start a program* entry that leads straight to the .bat file - not cmd.exe with parameters.

Comment: That won't work for some reason... Idk I am going to keep playing around with the user maybe that'll work...

Comment: @Radical924 what do you mean by "won't work"?

Comment: If you read my comment above the bat file will run but its commands do not execute... I will post my .bat that I have so far above in the comments.

Comment: I ended up getting it working... I used the invisible.vbs script thing on here: http://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file and followed the post and it all works now... Thanks though... idk why it wasn't working before but your post did make me look more into it and I found that post...

Answer (score 1):

I am using the "Startup" folder for bat files to be executed at the startup.

Copy your bat file in your "Startup" folder (for example `C:\Users\*your username*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`).

Replace `exit` by `pause` at the end of the bat file (`exit` is not needed here anyway). This is for testing purposes. The command prompt will not close until you will press a key. It is good way to see if there were any errors during the executing the commands from the bat file.

Remove the `pause` command when you are happy with the result.