# Shortcut with relative path

Tags: windows, shortcuts

I am trying to create a shortcut whose path is something like:

```
apps\bin\myapp.exe --userdir apps\conf\_user
```

This own't work because Windows wants a absolute path but this shortcut is stored on a USB stick and therefore I cannot hardcode the thing to C: or D: as it will change each time the USB is inserted into a new PC.

I am currently using a *.bat file to work around this but the CMD.EXE windows stays visible until it's physically closed -- kind of a PITA.

Any ideas???

Comment: any luck with %CD%\apps\ ? i haven't tried it, is just an idea

Comment: not a full answer, but depending on how you are starting your app (eg. If you are saying `CD apps`;then `Program.exe`; it will stay open until program.exe returns back. an alterantive would be  `cd apps`; then `start program.exe` which starts program.exe in it's own process (and lets the command execution move on down the batch file)

Answer (score 1):

You might like to check out this [question and accepted answer.](https://superuser.com/a/62646/128359) It will allow you to hide the Command window when running your .bat file. Pasted below for convenience.

**Solution 1:**

Save this one line of text as file `invisible.vbs`:

> CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """"
>   & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0,
>   False

To run any program or batch file invisibly, use it like this:

> wscript.exe
>   "C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs" "C:\Some
>   Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat"

To also be able to pass-on/relay a list of arguments use only two double quotes

> CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run ""
>   & WScript.Arguments(0) & "", 0,
>   False

Example: `Invisible.vbs "Kill.vbs ME.exe"`

**Solution 2:**

Use a command line tool to silently launch a process : [Quiet](https://superuser.com/a/62646/128359), [hidecon](http://code.kliu.org/misc/hidecon/) or [hideexec](http://code.kliu.org/misc/hideexec/).

Comment: or hstart (hidden start)

Comment: -1 if you're going to copy/paste an answer from elsewhere on superuser, then Don't.  Use a comment and link to it.

Comment: he posted it pointing out that it wasnt his and was from elsewhere on superuser. If it bothers you, click through and vote up the original answerer.

Comment: @barlop Also, this is an answer. His answer is just that someone else found a solution here. no reason to punish him for better search fu than the OP

Comment: I'm not downvoting his answer for his use of search, i'm downvoting it despite that, because it could've been just a comment(besides the fact that it isn't addressing the title so is not ideal as an answer to the title). I'm downvoting it because it's needless duplication and could've just been a comment. I don't care that he stated at the beginning that he was copy/pasting somebody else's superuser answer.   He should've just linked to it. Plus it looks like an underhanded way to score points to me. If he was just trying to help as he should be, and be concise, then link to it.

Comment: `start` would work just as well as it should return straight away with minimal CMD window exposure. As for copy and pasting an answer, I could've linked to the article I found on Google that had also stolen the SuperUser answer I borrowed, but wanted to avoid potential link rot.

Comment: @MichaelFrank  no, in the case of an answer that is offsite, it is worth pasting in in case the link goes dead. That is also why for example, pictures linked to from some non-superuser site, are stored locally in an imgur location for stackexchange that is maintained. And that is why when an answer from elsewhere applies, people often comment saying duplicate and link to it or just link to it. But in the case of an answer that is already on here, then it's already in the database, you shouldn't copy/paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

For thumb drives where the drive changes from computer to computer I use batch files (instead of shortcuts)where %~dp0 which is the equivalent of drive and path containing the batch file. If you just want the drive its %~d0\

@echo off
cd %~dp0apps\conf_user
%~dp0apps\bin\myapp.exe

Comment: I am using a batch file right now and relative paths seems to work fine, but I am growing more concerned over config files which may also have absolute paths not sure how I am going to get around that short of re-writing them with a script or something.

Comment: @Alex.Barylski what exactly do you mean when you say relative paths work for a batch (but presumably not for a shortcut), can you give an example in your question?  'cos you could plug your usb stick in and double click the batch file on your usb stick.. so can you give an example in your question?

Comment: what if you add the path for the config files to the path of the machine. That change will only stick until the batch file exits.