# Stop a "completly hidden batch file"

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit Home Premium.

My new internet connection is a bit buggy, and I need to keep reconnecting. To make sure my computer keeps connected while I'm away, I created a script that reconnects every 30 minutes. Since it runs constantly, I wanted to make it run hidden, and found a working way: solution 1 on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/62646/229977).

However, without the command window, I'm not sure **how to go about stopping the script** when I need to. What I'm doing is looking up the cmd.exe process in the task manager and stop it, but I keep wondering: **Is this a good way?** Is there a better, more direct way, **that doesn't require the task manager**?

Comment: Make another batch file to kill the first? It'd be some kind of brutal process hunger games.

Comment: Wi-Fi or wired Ethernet? Please advise. Some radio devices interfere with Wi-Fi on a cyclical basis, especially console gaming headsets. Many, many devices can use the unlicensed Wi-Fi bands and if they are not true Wi-Fi, nothing stops them from putting out radio interference which shreds a Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Good idea, not sure why I didn't think of that. Took me a bit, but got it working with taskkill. If you'd like to rewrite that as an answer, maybe referring to http://stackoverflow.com/q/16513288/2697421 , I would gladly accept it.

Comment: @K7AAY The connection is Wi-Fi, but the reconnection part is done, just looking for a way to kill the script. Thank you for your second comment, but as you can see in my previous comment, I found a way that works best for me (partially because when I use it, I can't stop picturing the "brutal process hunger games", I must admit).

Comment: @Sampaio I'm glad I've create a memory. Be thankful you aren't this guy though: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Classic-WTF-A-Crony-Joke.aspx

Comment: Just stay out of Sector 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just make another batch file to kill the first.

In your first batch file make sure you add:

```
@Echo Off
title batchname.bat
```

That way, in the second batch file you can kill it by calling:

```
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe /fi "windowtitle eq batchname.bat"
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513288/code-to-end-one-batch-file-with-another-can-anyone-assist), provided by [Sampaio](https://superuser.com/users/229977/sampaio).

Answer (score 0):

An easier Task Manager method would use

> schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 30 /tn "30 Minute Script" /tr \path\to\30min.vbs

- and the last line of *30min.vbs* sets up a new 30 minute job, to execute 30 minutes hence.

When you don't need it any more, kill the "30 Minute Script" with

> schtasks /end /tn "30 Minute Script"

- details at http://microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/