# How to solve error: There is no script engine for file extension ".cmd"

Tags: cmd.exe

I have created a .cmd file that I would like to run without bringing up a command window.  I am trying to do this by creating a shortcut on my desktop.  The target of that shortcut is: C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe "D:\MyFile.cmd".

I recently re-installed my Windows 8.1 OS.  Before the re-installation, the shortcut worked fine.  However, after the re-installation whenever I double-click it, I get the error:
Windows Script Host
There is no script engine for file extension ".cmd".

Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
[Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file)

Sorry for not doing a little more digging and finding this answer before posting my question.

Answer (score 0):

That's because CMD files has nothing to do with wscript.
You should run them through the command line (Cmd.exe), or just by double-clicking them.