# Windows - Run process on background after closing cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, process

I have a Python script which I want to run as a background process on Windows.

I can do that on Linux with:

```
python script.py &
```

and then disconnect the process from the terminal with:

```
disown
```

On Windows, all I have so far is this:

```
start /b python script.py
```

However, if I close the CMD window, the script stops running. Is there any extra command that I am missing here to keep the script running on the background?

Answer (score 10):

`start` should already be the right direction. However, `/b` attaches it to the same console. Now the problem is that when a console window is closed, any process associated with this console will also be closed.

You can either use `start` without `/b`, then it will run in a new console. If you want to run it in the background without a console window though, then you would need to use a VBScript or third-party tool: [Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way)

However, in that case you wouldn't see the stdout/stderr output anymore. You could redirect it to a file though, by wrapping it in a `cmd /c your_command > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt` call and starting this one through one of the aforementioned methods (VBScript, third-party tool, ...).

Alternatively, you could also hide your own console window before you exit. I just wrote a little one-line program which does exactly that (source code is basically `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE)`): http://share.cherrytree.at/showfile-24286/hide_current_console.exe

This way, you can use `start /b`, and when you want to "close" your console (technically hide it), you would run `hide_current_console & exit` which would hide the console and then close the cmd.exe process (not the python process) - in one line, since you can't type `exit` after the console was already hidden.

Comment: Where does `hide_current_console` comes from? Doesn't work on a W10 PC.

Comment: I tested it again, it still works. Where it comes from: Please read the post again, I showed the one line of source code this file has and linked a compiled hide_current_console.exe file to download...

Answer (score -1):

I found the following worked well for me:

```
run python script.py
```

*NOTE: This requires cygwin*

Comment: Oh, and on Linux instead of background (`&`) and `disown` I would suggest using `nohup`.

Comment: That command entered into a Windows cmd shell gives the following error: `'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable path or batch file.`.