# Is there any way to make Windows smart about different file types with same extension?

Tags: file-association, file-types, filetype

The problem is for `.ts` files which currently Windows identifies them as video format.

I want `.ts` files that are videos open with video player and `.ts` files that are TypeScript open with code editor.

Any solution?

Comment: You would have to write a helper app that is able to distinguish the two different kinds of files and launch the appropriate application. That is off-topic for [su]

Comment: Visual Studio has something like that

Comment: Maybe detect file content. I'd guess typescript is only text, where as the video format is likely different (binary? )

Answer (score 2):

A very simple-minded idea is to distinguish between the two cases by the size of the
file being launched, since video files are much larger.

You can create a program to intercept in Explorer the double-click on `.ts` files
that will launch either the player or an editor.
This can done even by just a `.bat` file that has the file as its parameter.

An (untested) model for such a `.bat` file is :

```
@echo off
setlocal
set maxbytesize=10000

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%1') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% LSS %maxbytesize% (
    editor.exe '%1'
) else (
    player.exe '%1'
)
```

You would need to designate this script as handler for `.ts` files.
See for that this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69826/165358).

If you wish to avoid the black rectangle in which the `.bat` script will
execute, see the post
[Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way).

Comment: Another way to do this would be to make your script call TrID (http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) with the name of the file and then launch the appropriate program depending on what filetype it returned.