# Making a DLL available for all windows programs (win10 pro x64)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, dll, opengl, system32

Due to the (not relevant for this question) restrictions of OpenGL implementation in Virtualbox (only OpenGL version 1.1 available, but I need at least version 2.0) I decided to use software implementation in form of a DLL (named **opengl32.dll**) which can be downloaded from here: ftp://ftp.blender.org/sergey/softwaregl/

One way to do it is to put the file **opengl32.dll** directly into the same directory as the executable file.

My question is: what is the best way to make this software implementation available to all the programs without copying the DLL files around.

Important notice: All the 32 bits applications need the file **opengl32.dll** from the directory [/win32/](ftp://ftp.blender.org/sergey/softwaregl/win32) of this FTP server, while all the 64 bits applications need the file **opengl32.dll** *(same name, but it's a different file!)* from the directory [/win64/](ftp://ftp.blender.org/sergey/softwaregl/win64). Thus if I have one 32 bit and one 64 bit application in a same directory on my computer, the solution of putting the DLL into the same folder doesn't work: it's not possible to have two different files with the same name in a same directory.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your 64bit `dll` to `c:\Windows\System32` and your 32 bit `dll` to `c:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Note, that on Windows 10 original `OpenGL32.dll` files are only accessible by `TrustedInstaller` user. So, to replace them you have to change ownership of those files to `Administrator`. For me it was not possible to do that using any UI, but command line approach worked. To do that, run the `Command Prompt` as administrator. Then use the following commands to delete the original `OpenGL32.dll` files:

`takeown /F C:\Windows\System32\OpenGL32.dll /A icacls C:\Windows\System32\OpenGL32.dll /T /grant administrators:F move C:\Windows\System32\OpenGL32.dll C:\Windows\System32\OpenGL32.dll.orig`

Same for `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` directory.

After that, just copy your own `OpenGL32.dll` to those locations as administrator.

**Edit:**
Software `Opengl32.dll` implementation can be downloaded also from https://fdossena.com/?p=mesa/index.frag

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to have two sub-folders like that :

```
Installation folder
    |--- Win32 DLL
    |--- Win64 DLL
```

The program's `.exe` is placed in the main folder, but is not directly called.
Instead it is started via a `.bat` file that checks whether Windows is 32- or
64-bits and starts the `.exe` in the context of the matching sub-folder.
A DLL is searched in several folders, one of which is the current folder.

See the post
[batch file to check 64bit or 32bit OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322308/batch-file-to-check-64bit-or-32bit-os).

If you are worried about the `.bat` file appearing as a black square window,
you may start it as hidden as described in the post
[Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way).
A GUI program that is started from such a hidden batch file will not itself be hidden.

Comment: What do you mean by the words "to start the .exe **in the context** of a subfolder"?

Comment: I mean conceptually to do `cd Win32DLL` or `cd Win64DLL` before executing `..\prog.exe`. Paths should be more explicitly written than this short version.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `KnownDLL` mechanism might help. Known DLL's bypass the filesystem search and instead are loaded from a single fixed directory. Conveniently, there's one KnownDLL directory for 64 bit processes and one KnownDLL32 directory for 32 bit processes.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit? 
googling by "knowndll" doesn't help much, alas.

Comment: @ilya: In short, " KnownDLL" is a list of DLL names cached by Windows, so it doesn't need to locate them on disk when you load them. The name comes from the registry key where they're listed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555749/microsoft-known-dll for details. By adding `opengl32.dll` to this list, you can tell Windows where to find `opengl32.dll` on disk.