# How to not change title with WinSCP in batch file

Tags: batch-file, winscp

I'm using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) in my batch file (the portable version) to download FTP files, however, whenever I run it from a batch file **it changes the window title**. **Is there any way I can avoid that?**

My complete script is [here on github](https://github.com/ITCMD/ftpchat/blob/master/ftpCHAT.bat)

But to summarize my use of WinSCP, it basically generates a temporary script file, executes it with `winscp.com`, redirects its output to another temporary file and parses the output for some keywords.

An example of execution:

```
WinSCP.com /open /script=t.ftp /ini=nul ftp://%ftpusr%:%ftppass%@%server% >test.ftp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot prevent `winscp.com` from changing console window title.

---

Note that a console window title is changed by `winscp.com` only, whose sole purpose is that it is a *console application*. As a console application, it inherits a console of the parent console application (if any), like that of `cmd.exe`, when executed from a batch file. Then it can write its output to it, instead of opening a separate console window, what would otherwise equivalent `winscp.exe /console` call do (`winscp.exe` is GUI application, so it cannot inherit a console window of parent process). Read about [WinSCP executables](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables).

But you seem to want to prevent users from seeing the output of `winscp.com` too. You only abuse the (hidden) output for error checking. That's not a very reliable approach. You better use WinSCP exit code to check for errors. See [How do I know that script completed successfully?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_result) If you need even more detailed error checking, you can use [XML logging](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging_xml).

Once you get rid of your abuse of WinSCP output, you can switch to `winscp.exe` with the same arguments. When `winscp.exe` is called with `/command` switch, but without `/console` switch, it runs the commands completely silently (and it does not change console title).

Though for such a complicated use, you should switch from plain WinSCP scripting to [WinSCP .NET assembly and PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell). Your code will be way cleaner and more robust.

---

For a quick solution, you can run `winscp.com` in its own hidden console.
See [Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/q/62525/213663).
(though contrary to most examples, you want to set the `bWaitOnReturn` argument to `True`).

You need your batch file to generate a `.vbs` script like this:

```vb
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd.exe /c ""C:\some\path\winscp.com"" /ini=nul /script=temp.ftp ftp://username:password@host > output.txt"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, true
```

And then run it from the batch file like:

```
cscript runwinscp.vbs
```

Comment: Well I handle individually the output of many of the commands. For instance, with file sharing section of my code (`:fileman`), I handle the results of the `ls` command to get a list of file names without downloading all the files. Is there a way to run `winscp.exe /command` and send output to a text file?

Comment: No. You should not parse WinSCP output anyway. If you need detailed results, parse XML log file. There’s even example for retrieving listing fron the log - https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging_xml#xslt

Comment: There is no native xml parser in batch code though.

Comment: You can download Microsoft `msxsl` (as you can see in the linked article) - though indeed doing such complex scripting in a batch file is not a good idea.

Comment: I searched for something like that last year for weeks and found nothing :/. Thanks.

Comment: I've realized that there's another easy solution for you. See my update answer.

Comment: that's perfect yes. I was missing `bWaitOnReturn` in the past

Comment: I'm a total noob, where do I put in the `bWaitOnReturn` in this script? It's not working with the `oShell.Run`. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: `true` is already there in my answer: `oShell.Run strArgs, 0, true`

Comment: I see, the true is for the attribute. Thanks

Comment: ```Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd.exe /c ""C:\Users\theBATeam\Documents\Batch\FTP-Chat\Bin\winscp.com"" /ini=nul /script=""C:\Users\theBATeam\Documents\Batch\FTP-Chat\Bin\temp.ftp"" ftp://username:pass@ftp.address.com > getWelcome.txt"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, true
``` isnt working for me. Any ideas why? The output into getWelcome.txt is blank, and it doesn't seem to execute anything since no files are downloaded or uploaded.

Comment: Handling of quotes by `cmd.exe` is very strange. Remove the quotes around `C:\Users\theBATeam\Documents\Batch\FTP-Chat\Bin\temp.ftp`.

Comment: Or this should work too: `Dim strArgs strArgs = "cmd.exe /c """"C:\Users\theBATeam\Documents\Batch\FTP-Chat\Bin\winscp.com"" /ini=nul /script=""C:\Users\theBATeam\Documents\Batch\FTP-Chat\Bin\temp.ftp"" ftp://username:pass@ftp.address.com"" > getWelcome.txt`

Comment: will either or both of those still work if there are spaces in the path?

Comment: The latter should work even with spaces.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, January’s release should have these in it. Merry Christmas!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87464/discussion-between-mark-deven-and-martin-prikryl).