# PowerShell: How to get the name of the selected file?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, regedit, arguments

I run a PowerShell script from the context menu on a selected file. But I struggle to find the way to simply get the file name of this file.

The file name selected is `1.mp3` which is inside the directory `sound`

I managed to extract some information about the selected item such as:

```
$FolderPath = Get-Location
$FolderName = [IO.Path]::GetFolderName($FolderPath)
```

I tried to get its file name using things like `$File_path = %1` (since [regedit use %1](https://superuser.com/a/1388131/669391) which is suppose to contain the path).

Comment: Check `$Args` in your script. See  `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Args` is an automatic variable,

Cite from `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`

> $Args
>         Contains an array of the undeclared parameters and/or parameter
>         values that are passed to a function, script, or script block.
>         When you create a function, you can declare the parameters by using the
>         param keyword or by adding a comma-separated list of parameters in
>         parentheses after the function name.