# How to hide Application's loading screen/window

Tags: window, virtual-desktop, application-launch

I use a program (Controller Editor from Native Instruments) on Windows 10 that I don't want to see when it's running (preferably on windows startup).

Now I've seen apps that can minimize to tray (although it's hard to find one that does so automatically from a specified setting/list without keyboard shortcuts) and I'm having trouble getting an application-window-hiding app.

I've learned to use vdesk to open the software on a background virtual desktop which is cool.

The problem is that while the application is loading it has like... a loading screen window: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYQNb.jpg)

Even when the app is loading on a different virutal desktop, the loading screen appears on the current desktop. How can I hide this?

I think a window hiding app might help but i'm not sure if it'll only apply to the actual app window and not the loading screen.

I've also read that you can turn almost any Windows app into a Service, i'm also wondering if that would work.

Thanks for any and all considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Turning your Windows app into a system service is not recommended, since it is not
written to work as a service and may cause problems.

Better solutions would be:

- The post
  [Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way)
  lists several ways of running an invisible program.
  If any of them work with this program, you could put the batch file inside the
  user's or system's Startup folder.
- You could use the
  [Task Scheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page)
  to schedule executing the program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll look into it and let you know. Thank you.