# Wake up HDD during boot

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-explorer

In my computer, there is an internal SSD with the OS and all the programs and an internal HDD with all the data. Every time I want to access this data via Windows File Explorer, I have to wait quite some time (its 2 TB of data in one folder) after opening the HDDs folders until all the files can be accessed. Is it possible to "preload" these files during booting so that the waiting time when accessing the HDD is reduced?

Comment: Might help to document the HDD model, interface type (SATA?), & motherboard model. The last one might help if something in the BIOS can wake the drive on boot. Knowing what type of files may also help (video, pictures, etc.) as its could be a Windows cache thing (ex: Thumbs.db)

Comment: Any working solution will have the side effect of slowing down the boot time by as much as it takes now to fully open the file explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either command: `explorer d:\` or `dir d:\` in a scheduled task or in a [startup folder](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-10-startup-folder/) might help.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve that without bringing up a new expolorer window into the front?

Comment: It may be best to use `dir d:\ ` as I'm thinking hiding explorer might be challenging, but feel free to prove me wrong & help others! 
-If running as scheduled task: tick the Hidden checkbox or change user to System (need to run task scheduler as admin). 
-If you're doing batch file in startup folder: put this in first line of batch file: `CONSOLESTATE /Min`. Here are some other links to hide batch file: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_hideconsole.php https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way

Comment: Worked like this: consolestate /min
start /min explorer.exe "D:\"

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked with the following code:

```
consolestate /min

start /min explorer.exe "D:\"
```