# Create browser bookmark to relative path within portable installation folder

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I'm distributing a portable version of Firefox with some addons pre-installed, and it's meant to be used with some local HTML files I'm distributing along with it. Is there any way I can create bookmarks that link to relative file paths, pointing to files within the portable browser's own folder? It seems the only way I can make bookmarks work with local files is using absolute file paths, and that won't work with a portable distribution. It'd be nice if I could save my users the trouble of having to create those bookmarks themselves.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is starting Firefox by a `.bat` script that may look
like this:

```
%echo off
subst w: .
start "" firefox.exe
```

This will create the drive `w:` that is the same as the current folder.
You may then define all your bookmarks as `w:relative-path`.

Notes: The
[SUBST command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst)
will output a non-fatal error that will not block the execution.
The
[START command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start)
will start Firefox outside of the `.bat` script so the script itself can terminate.

The batch file itself will be seen as a black flash on the screen. If you wish
to avoid that, see
[Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way).