# Change Chrome Bookmark Location and Nothing Else

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

BLUF: I want to change the bookmark file location to a network folder without moving my entire profile (currently using --user-data-dir).

My company does not allow logging into Chrome, so I can't sync my bookmarks. They also block all google apps, so I can't use things like Google Bookmarks.
My Windows profile is (mostly) on a server, so I'd like to move JUST my bookmarks out of C: AppData to a network drive location.
I'm currently using the --user-data-dir switch in my chrome.exe shortcut, but I don't need or want all that cached data to write to the server constantly.

Any insight would be appreciated!

-Edit: I just realized GPO could be an option, though it'll have to be an IT request to edit.

Comment: Are you allowed to install apps? For example for syncing the bookmarks file from it current location.

Comment: Have you considered using a portable version of chrome so you can place it anywhere you want, including a thumbdrive?

Comment: @harrymc Chrome extensions are also blocked. Windows apps/SW have to be approved and installed by admins.

Comment: @LPChip Can't use USB drives (unless an approved encrypted one, which I don't have.)

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that your account is not admin and in addition an extremely strict
security policy requires you to ask for permissions for almost everything,
you might adopt the policy of DIY to write your own backup job.

Let's say file `bookmarks.bat` contains :

```
@ECHO OFF
:loop
  copy "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\bookmarks" "\\server\path\"
  timeout /t 1800 > NUL
goto loop
```

This batch file will loop, copying every 30 minutes the bookmarks file to
the network path, until you kill it from the Task Manager or turn off
the computer.

If in addition you would like the batch file to be invisible, see the post
[Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way).

Comment: Not a bad idea. Of course, I can't run .bat, .cmd, or .ps either. I _can_ open that in a terminal manually, though, and just do that every time I log on. Kind of a half-solution, though, and I'll keep looking for a re-direct method.

Comment: I wish Chrome had a bookmarks-only version of the `--user-data-dir` method.

Comment: What about VBScript? Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260740/copy-a-file-from-one-folder-to-another-using-vbscripting).