# Run a .bat file silently?

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file I am using to control the volume of my monitor using DDC/CI. I was using nircmd to run it silently, but as of the newest version of Windows 10, that no longer works.

Below is my batch file:

```
title CmmVolume
nircmd.exe win hide ititle "CmmVolume"

cmm.exe /ChangeValue Primary 62 %1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way)

Comment: No, that does not work properly with parameters.

Comment: Check if this is typo or not ? `ititle` to `title`

Comment: Not a typo. @Hackoo

Comment: @JasonAxelrod Where we can download the extrenal tool ? I want to make a test !

Comment: What about using `nircmd.exe exec hide cmm.exe /ChangeValue Primary 62 %1`?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is run your batch file **minimized**, which gives virtually the same effect:

1. Create a shortcut to the batch file.
2. Right-click the shortcut and choose Properties.
3. In the Properties dialog, locate the `Run` dropdown and choose Minimized.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your bat should attend to some elementary points that are missing and that possibly this would be causing the execution to fail, but anyway, in my tests the adjustments listed below worked perfectly:

**1.** Enter the folder of your bat **`"%~dp0"`**

**2.** Apply the full path to all executable files

**3.** using the latest version of **`NirCMD`** on Windows 10

**4.** Replace **`ititle`** to **`stitle`**

```bat
@echo off && title <nul 

>nul taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq "CmmVolume" 2>nul 

cd /d "%~dp0" && title CmmVolume

"C:\Users\ecker\Downloads\Nircmd\Nircmd.exe" win hide stitle "CmmVolume"

>>"%~dp0\log.log"  echo\"c:\add\full\path\to\cmm.exe" /ChangeValue Primary 62 %1

>"%tmp%\VBS_play.vbs" echo\CreateObject("Wscript.Shell"^).Run "wmplayer /play /close ""%windir%\Media\notify.wav""", 0, False

wscript "%tmp%\VBS_play.vbs" & timeout /t 1 >nul & del /q /f  "%tmp%\VBS_play.vbs"
```

---

**Obs.:** The vbs for execution/play audio and the log are for verification of execution in hidden/background mode...