# Robocopy started hidden with vbs script not showing exit codes in Task Scheduler

Tags: vbscript, robocopy, task-scheduler

Trying solutions [here](https://superuser.com/a/62646/12543) and [here](https://serverfault.com/a/9039) works fine, except in Task Scheduler *Last run* result always shows as `The operation completed successfully. (0x0)` instead of `0x2` or `0x3` without vbs:
[image: 0x2]

Is it possible to get [exit codes](https://adamtheautomator.com/robocopy-the-ultimate/#Exit_Codes) with vbs script?

Comment: you probably need to catch them and set it yourself, and depends what you put in the script, the exit code of the script will be the last command executed, so if you have a set or echo or whatever, that will be recorded as result.

Comment: Ah ok. No idea how vbs works so hoping someone will have something to paste :)

Comment: each command you run will return the errorlevel code, if successful 0 otherwise depending on the command, so you need to catch the errorlevel immediately after the command was run, with the notice that reading the errorlevel code will reset the errorlevel code to 0 as the command to get the errorlevel will always succeed...