# AutoHotKeky: Run a CMD command in the background

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to write an AHK script to be able to switch between portrait and landscape mode by a single key. Here is my first attempt not exactly what I am looking for. I am not an expert in the AHK scraping language. The script works but it shows the CMD windows for a few seconds while running the display.exe command. How to prevent opening CMD window.

```
F14::
    T := !T
    If T
     Run display /rotate 0 /device 3 /display none,,Hide
    else
     Run display /rotate 90 /device 3 /display none,,Hide
    return
```

http://noeld.com/programs.asp?cat=misc#display

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which `display` program you are using, but here is some advice.

You could put the commands in `.bat` files and hide them using one of the
answers in the post
[Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way).

As another solution, use the
[iRotate](https://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm)
utility that does not create a CMD box.

The following AHK script, adapted from a
[github gist](https://gist.github.com/telekineticyeti/25ce9e6435ea1724ff2576e3efe865f1),
uses
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1-4</kbd>
for rotating:

```
MyPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\iRotate\iRotate.exe

^F1::Run %MyPath% /2:rotate=0
^F2::Run %MyPath% /2:rotate=180
^F3::Run %MyPath% /2:rotate=270
^F4::Run %MyPath% /2:rotate=90
```

Comment: Thanks, I use http://noeld.com/programs.asp?cat=misc#display
It seems iRotate does not support the command line and its default shortcut keys are not configurable.

my AHK works great I just prefer not to see the CMD box.

Comment: The shortcut keys in the AHK script can be anything at all. Also, the above script uses the iRotate command-line. So I don't understand your comment.