# How do I make my batch script execute 2 commands in the right order?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Okay so I managed to make the batch file start up my completely potato game on my potato laptop (this is just a laptop for coding practice, side projects, surfing the internet etc) upon logging in. Great.

But now how do I make the same batch file execute another command separately, namely that upon quitting the game, I"ll be automatically logged out of my win 10 user account?

I know it"ll be "logoff.exe" I think, but how do I make the script get the order of commands right? ie first launch the game and IF I quit the game it"ll log me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF

START "" "steam://rungameid/40970"
Timeout /T 25 /Nobreak


:LOOP
tasklist | find /i "STRONGHOLD" >nul 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  GOTO CONTINUE
) ELSE (
  ECHO STRONGHOLD is still running
  Timeout /T 5 /Nobreak
  GOTO LOOP
)

:CONTINUE
echo exited
SHUTDOWN /l /f
```

Comment: So if my script so far looks like this:                                                          at echo off

start steam://rungameid/40970

at echo on
 then how do I do what you said?

Comment: Stronghold Crusader HD... good game. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177695/how-to-wait-for-a-process-to-terminate-to-execute-another-process-in-batch-file/8197920 I edited the answer above. Try that, if it doesn't work we may have to make it more complicated. I don't have Steam installed so I can't test it.

Comment: Okay so I copy pasted exactly what you wrote, the last part and it did launched the game for me but upon exiting the game it wouldn"t force log me out

Comment: @ProprietaryCloudGaming I added another way.

Comment: It's Stronghold Crusader (32 bits)

Comment: Try this. Should work. I am assuming the filename of the executable is something like stronghold.exe

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Is there a way to make the batch file do exactly what I want but without the cmd prompt window popping up during either of these 2 actions (launching the game on startup + force-logging out the user upon exiting the game)?

Comment: I haven't tried it but you can try https://github.com/stbrenner/SilentCMD or  https://www.battoexeconverter.com/ or you can create a .vbs script that runs the batch file invisibly as explained over at https://superuser.com/a/62646/1482432

Comment: Why doesn"t the advanced bat to exe converter run the exe file silently without the cmd prompt window popping up?

Comment: @ProprietaryCloudGaming https://i.imgur.com/Hu2mGby.png You need to select the "Start invisible"-checkbox. After you clicked the Build EXE button.

Comment: @ProprietaryCloudGaming To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: I cant see the Build EXE button, where is it?

Comment: @ProprietaryCloudGaming https://i.imgur.com/htQj1FY.png

Comment: thank you. What does the Include Admin Manifest button do?

Comment: @ProprietaryCloudGaming  It makes the program require admin privileges. You don't need those in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF

:: This batch file start program1, after closing it logs off pc

TITLE my auto progam starter and loggoff on quit(sorry for the typing
errors)

ECHO Please wait... starting program1

ECHO ============================

START /WAIT steam://rungameid/40970

ECHO logging you off now...

TASKKILL steam
```

(or what the steam process is called, im not sure, should close both the steam app and the game, if not add additional takkill for the gameprocess)

shutdown -l

Comment: We tried that, it didn't work in this case.

Comment: wow nice - and you tried it 1 second after i wrote it? :) either way the author can try and check should have no issue - you first echo off all the commands - the sttart /wait is the way to do it without any lagg as it it simply waits for process to end then runs the logoff at the end of the process

Comment: It was in an older version of my answer. OP tried it, it didn't work, hence the current method.

Comment: could be an issue with the game itself - not the commands - perhaps try adding -f and the end to force the loggoff - - but could be that the game process simply takes a while to end - you can force end it on click but no idea what game it is - it might break saving if there is such a thing in that game - i use this for heroes 3 and it sometimes takes 10 min before it loggs me off after i close cause the process keeps lagging for a few minutes till it full closes like any process in windows

Comment: i think /w doesn't work cause the start command runs a steam shortcut, not the .exe directly. Heroes of Might and Magic III was an awesome game. OP is running Stronghold Crusader.

Comment: i see, that means there are 2 processes that neeed to be opened then closed prior to the 
shutdown -l

i reccomend try to observe them via process manager as tehre could be more then two - then add them both - should work , problem is console cant tell spawned process from original process - meaning if it is a steam game that spawns steam app and the game it will treat them as one when opening but wont know they are both closed - try to add the steam.exe and the gmae process speratly one under the other might solve it