# How to prevent the bouncing Taskbar icons inferno in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11, taskbar

Every minute, as my master script adds another cmd.exe instance in the background, my cmd.exe Taskbar icon group now "bounces" or "shrink-expands" in an extremely distracting animation.

How do I stop this madness? It has started in Windows 11 and was not done on Windows 10.

It does not "flash", and the one taskbar setting about disabling "flashing" doesn't impact this.

I've looked in Winaero Tweaker without finding any way to remove this. It's going to drive me insane if it continues. I can't use my computer while constantly seeing (and waiting for) pointless, distracting animations. What possible reason could there be for this to exist in the first place?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is clear for me. Every time he starts a new window, The taskbar-GUI pops up adding this window to the stack of existing windows.
To the question: I am not aware how to disable that GUI behaviour, but you might start new instances in the same cmd-window by using the "call"-statement.

Comment: @Carsten They need to run in separate instances. They are each a PHP CLI script.

Comment: Can you go with "start /b" to launch them all in the same window? If not, then you need to go via the (ugly) vbs-workaround: https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way

Comment: Simply use a terminal app that uses tabs, like ConEmu.

Comment: @Carsten Launching them "in the same window" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Destroy666 Both PowerShell and Windows Terminal are so horribly inefficient that my powerful computer's CPU and RAM is exhausted with only 25-100 instances of either, unlike with cmd.exe.

Comment: @TykellB Windows Terminal is kind of inefficient for me too, ConEmu not. And not "instances" but "tabs" in one instance like I said. You can configure ConEmu to open everything in new tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I have (by random chance) discovered the solution:

***Settings, Accessibility, Visual effects, "Animation Effects" = off.***

I first tried to uncheck "Animations in the taskbar" in the separate "Performance option" GUI box, but that didn't have any effect. It has to be done through the other settings GUI, under "Accessibility"...

This kind of thing gives me grey hairs.

Comment: Sadly, this switch will disable all animations in all apps, including smooth scrolling in Firefox. The option "Animations in the taskbar" should disable it, I've reported it here: https://aka.ms/AAn39ap

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 11 taskbar does not expose many customization options.
Perhaps your best bet is to try a third-party replacement.

I don't have any recommendation to give here, so here is a list of candidates:

- [Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/)
  (€6.99)
- [TaskbarXI](https://github.com/ChrisAnd1998/TaskbarXI)
- [10 Beautiful Dock for Windows 11/10 PC](https://firewallauthority.com/best-dock-for-windows/)
  describes mostly MacOS-inspired docks : Objectdock, RocketDock,XWindows Dock, Circle Dock, RK Launcher,
  Nexus Dock, SliderDock, Appetizer, Multibar, Aqua Dock.

Answer (score 0):

There are very limited options for customizing the Windows 11 Task Bar.  I suggest you not use 3rd party apps to manage the task bar. I do not use such apps and my Task Bar behaves properly.

Also adjust your master script so that it does not interfere with the Task Bar. Since the Task Bar cannot be readily customized, this will be the best approach.

Windows 11 has limits that early Windows systems did not have, but is now providing asked for features like Tabbed Explorer and similar.

You can also use Power Shell terminal sessions with multiple tabs that may help you.

Comment: Regarding "adjust your master script so that it does not interfere with the Task Bar", I don't understand what you mean. It launches PHP CLI scripts, which means cmd.exe instances, which means they must necessarily show up in the Taskbar.

Comment: As for PowerShell, or Windows Terminal, I have done extensive testing of these and they cause the computer to crawl on its knees from overloading the CPU and memory regardless of whether you use tabs or multiple instances.

Comment: I do not think the latter is caused by Task Bar but instead by the script. There is an overload somewhere. Perhaps this is what is interfering with the Task Bar (that is what I meant).

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you mean now.

Comment: I have not seen bouncing Task Bar icons (3 Windows 11 machines). So I am trying to imagine what is causing this.

Comment: @John he is talking about opening 100 instances of cmd.exe. Did you try that with taskbar and a script?

Comment: 100 instances of cmd.exe.   ........    No, I do not do that.